# Scala upper type bounds and parent classes

Tags: scala, types, type-bounds

I really like using upper type bounds to give some flexibility to what my constructions can take. However, I really don't know any of the principles behind it as I find with the following code:

```
object BoundsTest {
  abstract trait Service
  class Collection[T <: Service] extends collection.mutable.HashMap[Symbol, collection.mutable.Set[T]] with collection.mutable.MultiMap[Symbol, T]
  type Actives[T <: Service] = collection.mutable.HashMap[Symbol, T]
  class Library[T <: Service](collection: Collection[T], actives: Actives[T])
  private val libraries = new collection.mutable.HashMap[Symbol, Library[Service]]
  def setLibrary[T <: Service](name: Symbol, library: Library[T]) {
    libraries += name -> library
  }
}
```

I'm trying to that my classes can use an subclass of `Service` as long as it's consistent. However, this doesn't work:

```
$ scalac test.scala 
test.scala:10: error: type mismatch;
 found   : com.bubblefoundry.BoundsTest.Library[T]
 required: com.bubblefoundry.BoundsTest.Library[com.bubblefoundry.BoundsTest.Service]
Note: T <: com.bubblefoundry.BoundsTest.Service, but class Library is invariant in type T.
You may wish to define T as +T instead. (SLS 4.5)
    libraries += name -> library
                         ^
```

The problem is, I think, in how (and when?) I define `libraries`, as if I make the following changes everything compiles successfully:

```
// private val libraries = new collection.mutable.HashMap[Symbol, Library[Service]]
def setLibrary[T <: Service](name: Symbol, library: Library[T]) {
  new collection.mutable.HashMap[Symbol, Library[T]] += name -> library
}
```

How can I declare a `libraries` HashMap such that it has multiple `Library`s with different `Service`s? Is it possible to refer to `Service` here or is that impossible?

Or am I barking completely up the wrong tree? Thanks!

Answer (score 11):

In Scala parameterized types are invariant by default, e.g. for `Cage[A]` a `Cage[Bird]` is *not* a `Cage[Animal]`. But you can make a type covariant or even contravariant by means of variance declarations, e.g. `Cage[+A](a: A)`, and this is what the compiler tries to tell you in the error message.

Now it is not always possible to make a type parameter covariant. This will only work if the type variable is only used in so called positive occurrences. Or put another (not 100% correct) way, if your class is immutable. In your case, it would work. So all you have to do is add a `+` to the definition of `Library`:

```
class Library[+T <: Service](collection: Collection[T], actives: Actives[T])
```

Answer (score 5):

As the compile error helpfully says, the class `Library` is invariant. That is:

> `Library[S] <: Library[T]` iff `S <: T`

does not hold. This property is called **covariance** and is a property of generic type parameters. The reason that this is causing a compiler error is that your Map expects `Library[Service]` as its value type and you are trying to add a `Library[T]` (which, due to the lack of covariance, is not a `Library[Service]`, even though `T <: Service`)

If your `Library` class is immutable, then you should be able to add a `+` to the type parameter to indicate to `scalac` that Library *is* covariant in its type.